# Accessing Mathematica remotely

Tags: remote-access

I am trying to access Mathematica(graphical version) of my institute remotely. We setup the remote server and able to login via ssh. The problem I am facing is that Mathematica is very unresponsive even while typing. The speed of my computer remotely is around 10 Mbps and my institute has good enough speed.

Is the unresponsiveness is due to network speed or any other reason?

I have multiple notebooks which are interlinked(in the sense that functions are defined in different notebooks and variables are shared across them). So I am not sure how to run them from a terminal.

I am not well-versed in ssh and related stuff, so detailed answer/comments will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I found a hack: Use team viewer for accessing the system remotely. But I still appreciate any comments/solutions.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but WRI often strikes generous site-licensing deals with academic institutions. You may be able to install Mathematica for free on your personal computer, therefore avoiding the need to ssh in. I imagine [WRI sales](http://www.wolfram.com/company/contact/sales/) would be happy to tell you the terms of your school's site license.